# Как узнать адрес сервера

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Можно ли как-то получить адрес, на котором запущен GAE-сервер, для дальнейшего использования в серверной части кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, у Google-App-Engine нет для этого специально API. Но можно использовать метод getServerName класса [javax.servlet.ServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html), если это Java.

Comment: Да, верно. Это вообще вечная проблема, что имя сервера доступно только в определённом контексте.. в общем случае нет способа надёжно определить собственный адрес.